# SharePoint 2010 using web service to insert a data that has a lookup into external BCS list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've got a 2 SharePoint lists:

List A: This is an external list that's using Business Connectivity Services to connect to CRM. 
List B: This list contains a lookup field that linked into List A.

I am using the SharePoint web service: http://myserver/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx, to insert the data.

**Problem:** The value is inserted, however, it's not linked into BCS. (i.e. When I go to edit mode in the inserted list item, the field is blank).

**Methods tried:** I have tried using various fields in my List A, including the ID Field and other fields, but none works. I have also tried retrieving List A items using the web service, and use the value pattern (in this case: it's just the customer name in CRM), but it still doesnt work.

**Possible cause of error:** The value pattern of the BCS inserted is wrong.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Your BCS is not confugured perfectly. Try to create BCS again with help of an msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup fields store value in form ID;#Value. ID is parent list item ID and vlaue is parent lookup column value. so if you are updating/adding any value to this column please add this in format ID;#Value